# WHERE IN give me different results when ran in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, laravel

When I run the following query in phpMyAdmin

```
    SELECT 
        locations.name,
        locations.id,
        locations.lon,
        locations.lat,
        locations_categories.category_id as catId,
        locations_categories.location_id as locId,
        haversine(40,90,locations.lon,locations.lat) as distance
    FROM locations_categories, locations  
    WHERE locations.id = locations_categories.location_id
    AND locations_categories.category_id IN ("9","1","7")  
    ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

It gives me the following results, which are correct.

[image]

But When I run the following in my Laravel Application it only returns the locations with catId of 9.

```
        // dump($request->categories);
        $categories = implode('","',$request->categories);

        //dd($categories);


        $statement = <<<'ENDSTATEMENT'
        SELECT 
            locations.name,
            locations.id,
            locations.lon,
            locations.lat,
            locations_categories.category_id as catId,
            locations_categories.location_id as locId,
            haversine(?,?,locations.lon,locations.lat) as distance
        FROM locations_categories, locations  
        WHERE locations.id = locations_categories.location_id
        AND locations_categories.category_id IN (?)  
        ORDER BY `distance` ASC
ENDSTATEMENT;

    $locations = DB::select($statement, array($request->lon, $request->lat, $categories));
```

The results of the

```
dd($categories);
```

is the following screenshot

[image]

My question is, Why does this work and return all the values needed in PhpMyAdmin but not when ran within the application??

Comment: As simple as: `"9","1","7"` are three different values whereas `"9","1","7"` is treated as single string with additional quoting around it.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I noticed that too and I figured that was the issue but I got confused when it still searched for the 9. Do you have any idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Laravel has a `whereIn` function, which accepts a PHP array of values.  But, there doesn't seem to be any way to directly bind a PHP array the way you want to do it.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45710633) for some options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Laravel code here, rather than a single raw query.  This allows you to take advantage of the `whereIn` function, which can correctly bind a PHP array of values to the `WHERE` expression.

```
$locations = DB::table('locations_categories as lc')
    ->join('locations', 'locations.id', '=', 'lc.location_id')
    ->whereIn('lc.category_id', $request->categories)
    ->selectRaw('locations.name, locations.id, locations.lon, locations.lat,'
        . 'lc.category_id as catId,'
        . 'lc.location_id as locId,'
        . 'haversine(?, ?, locations.lon,locations.lat) as distance',
    [$request->lon, $request->lat])
->get();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! im going to make a few edits to your answer with the exact working code and then I will accept as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question has to do with how bound variables are implemented, combined with type coercion.

The bound `?` is replaced by a single value.  This isn't a simple search-and-replace into the SQL statement.  So, in `locations_categories.category_id IN (?)` the value of `?` is literally the whole value `9","1","7`.  But, why does that still return results where `locations_categories.category_id = 9`?

Because of type coercion.  I'm assuming that `locations_categories.category_id` is a numeric and not a character type column in your schema.  Therefore, when the SQL is executed, the string value on the right-hand side, `9","1","7` is being coerced into a numeric representation, which happens to be `9`.  You can see that more explicitly here:

```
mysql> select cast('9","1","7' as signed);
+-----------------------------+
| cast('9","1","7' as signed) |
+-----------------------------+
|                           9 |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.05 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                        |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '9","1","7' |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

The raw query has to be like this and pass an array of parameters to bind to the select:

```
SELECT 
    locations.name,
    locations.id,
    locations.lon,
    locations.lat,
    locations_categories.category_id as catId,
    locations_categories.location_id as locId,
    haversine(:req_lon, :req_lat, locations.lon, locations.lat) as distance
FROM locations_categories, locations  
WHERE 
    locations.id = locations_categories.location_id AND 
    locations_categories.category_id IN (:cat0, :cat1, :cat2)  
ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

Use that code with parameters to bind:

```
$categories = ["9","1","7"]; // example

$bind = [];
foreach($categories as $k => $cat) {
    $bind['cat'.$k] = $cat;
}
$listCat = implode(', ', array_keys($bind));

// add others filters
$bind['req_lon'] = $request->lon;
$bind['req_lat'] = $request->lat;

$sql = 
"   SELECT 
        locations.name,
        locations.id,
        locations.lon,
        locations.lat,
        locations_categories.category_id as catId,
        locations_categories.location_id as locId,
        haversine(:req_lon, :req_lat, locations.lon, locations.lat) as distance
    FROM locations_categories, locations  
    WHERE 
        locations.id = locations_categories.location_id AND 
        locations_categories.category_id IN ({$listCat})  
    ORDER BY `distance` ASC";

$locations = DB::select($sql, $bind);
```